# Share content on an iOS native app via messages or email with long enough trial

Tags: ios, messageui

I'm currently developing an iOS native application, with a custom MySQL database.

Once a user has shared content (media) through the application to a friend (that doesn't have the application) how can I ensure that the trail is long enough so that once downloaded, and registered on the application, it knows and points the new user straight to the shared content.

Each post has a postID stored in the database. How could I ensure that the postID was kept through-out the process?

Thanks a lot, really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "trail" when installing an app. Once your app is installed, you could have the user tap a custom URL ([URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)) in their browser that you would support in your app, or do it based on user registration.